# Real example for PWA application complete payment transaction offline

Tags: online-payment, payment

The new standard [PWA](https://stories.scandiweb.com/pwa-is-now-wait-but-why-1df252bc4ee2) provides ability for eCommerce websites to work offline. In theory this also includes the checkout part that complete the purchase by paying. 
 But, **can someone let me know about real eCommerce website that actually implemented it and *allow customer to pay offline*? How did they do it?** by storing the users requests as a pending payment and do it later when the device from which transaction was done is back online?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, it doesn't PWA might do some loading and token stuff but to upload on web and to get on DB you need internet. You need those stuff for transaction. Company also needs to know whether you paid or not and it needs internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't, really.

You **can** "fake" an offline order with a PWA, making use of a payment method that supports the [Payment Request API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Payment_Request_API) (which is still in its early-ish stages) to create a "token" that the device can then upload to the payment provider & validate the payment later; but payment can't be taken if there is no internet connection.

The main goal of a PWA is to offer a native mobile app-like experience; you can add them to your homebar (visit a PWA in Android/iOS and then hit "Add to Home Screen"), visit them offline etc. However, even a native app can't really take offline payments.